# Is there a way to find out all shortcuts registered with Windows?

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

In C#, how can I find all the shortcut keys, that are currently listed as Global shortcuts. For instance, Windows + L -> Locks the desktop. Windows + E starts Windows Explorer.

CTRL + SHIFT + SOMEKEY
CTRL + ALT + SOMEKEY

There are quite a few shortcuts already present and I wouldn't like to hijack a shortcut key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only way is to attempt to register the hotkey and see if it succeeds. According to the documentation for [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms911003.aspx):

> RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have already been registered by another hot key.

There isn't an `EnumHotKeys` or any equivalent listed in the docs for [Keyboard Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms907593.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Ken. Actually, I had an application, for which I created a shortcut and pinned to Start menu, and assigned a shortcut. Later on I registerd a Hotkey using AutoHotKey. I found that AHK overwrote my hotkey for the application.